# How to save the searched item from search bar and display the saved list from sharedprefernce in flutter

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

I a trying to save the searched item from searchbar to sharedpreference and want to display the list of searched list in other page but unable to achieve it. Below is my code how I am saving and retrieving it from the sharedprefernce.

I have updated my code please go through it.

**Update**
I have query which I am passing it to the url and getting the list directly

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<Ayurwikilist> ayurwikilist = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Ayurwiki'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          new IconButton(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.search),
            onPressed: () {
              showSearch(
                  context: context,
                  delegate: CustomSearchDelegate(ayurwikilist));
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: _body(),
    );
  }

class CustomSearchDelegate extends SearchDelegate {
  List<Ayurwikilist> ayurwikilist = [];
  CustomSearchDelegate(this.ayurwikilist);

  Future<Ayurwikilist> fetchPost() async {
    final response = await http.get(
        'https://www.example.org/api.php?action=query&list=search&srsearch=$query&utf8=&format=json');
    print(
        'https://www.example.org/api.php?action=query&list=search&srsearch=$query&utf8=&format=json');
    return Ayurwikilist.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
  }

  @override
  ThemeData appBarTheme(BuildContext context) {
    assert(context != null);
    final ThemeData theme = Theme.of(context);
    assert(theme != null);
    return theme;
  }

 @override
 List<Widget> buildActions(BuildContext context) {
   return [
     IconButton(
       icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
       onPressed: () async{
         query = '';
         SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
         prefs.setString('name', "$query");
         print(query);
       },
     ),
   ];
 }

  @override
  Widget buildLeading(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
      onPressed: () {
        close(context, null);
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }

  @override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<Ayurwikilist>(
      future: fetchPost(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          print(snapshot.data.toString());
          return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.query.search.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                var title = snapshot.data.query.search[index].title;
                return GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => Detailpage(
                            snapshot.data.query.search[index].title,
                            // 'images/ayurwiki.png'
                          ),
                        ));
                  },
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: Text(title),
                  ),
                );
              });
        } else {
          return Center(
            child: Text(
              'Search in ayurwiki',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 18),
            ),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

```
class _HistoryState extends State<History> {

var myName;

 getCredential() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var query = prefs.getString('query');
    setState(() {
      myName = query;
    });
    print('item : $query');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title:Text('Rcently viewed item'),
      ),
      body: Container(
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
          child: myName == null ? Text('No items') : Text('$myName'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Update**

```
Future<Ayurwikilist> fetchPost() async {
    final response = await http.get(
        'https://www.example.org/api.php?action=query&list=search&srsearch=$query&utf8=&format=json');
    print(
        'https://www.example.org/api.php?action=query&list=search&srsearch=$query&utf8=&format=json');
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setStringList('name', query as List);
    return Ayurwikilist.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
  }
```

```
getCredential() async {
   SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
   var name = prefs.getStringList('name');
   setState(() {
     myName = name;
   });
   print('item : $name');
 }
```

Comment: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59860840/how-to-use-searchdelegate-to-show-recent-search-history-in-flutter/59860841#59860841)

Answer (score 1):

you should call getCredential() function in initState

```
class _HistoryState extends State<History> {

 var myName;

 initState(){
    super.initState();
    getCredential();
 }

 getCredential() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var query = prefs.getString('query');
    setState(() {
      myName = query;
    });
    print('item : $query');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title:Text('Rcently viewed item'),
      ),
      body: Container(
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
          child: myName == null ? Text('No items') : Text('$myName'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

update:

```
Future<Ayurwikilist> fetchPost() async {
    query = 'something you need';
    final response = await http.get(
        'https://www.example.org/api.php?action=query&list=search&srsearch=$query&utf8=&format=json');
    print(
        'https://www.example.org/api.php?action=query&list=search&srsearch=$query&utf8=&format=json');
    prefs.setString('name', query);
    return Ayurwikilist.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
  }
```

Comment: its returning null

Comment: because your query is null
lock at your BuildAction function, in onPressed you set query = '', then set sharedprefernce with a null query

Comment: where should I declare in order to get the search context to sharedpreference.

Comment: where is your search widget ?

Comment: I have updated my code please can you go through it.

Comment: first of all you should fill query variable then call fetchpost() function
then set shared Preferences after receiving data in fetchpost() function
in this case you can set query with dummy data, but you should make an input for getting query data from user

Comment: i update my answer
check this and if you can get data from shared preferences in _HistoryState i told you how add textFormField to get user input query

Comment: Yes, I am now getting the query string. I am having one more  query when I am trying to get the list for string by setting the prefs.setStringList('name', query as List) it returning nothing in query search and as well not getting list

Comment: setStringList only accept a list of strings not a string as list did mean you cannot set your query variable with setStringList you should make a List<String> then fill it and after all set it in shared preferences