# how to make history with textfield in flutter?

Tags: list, flutter, dart, widget, bloc

```
class _SimpleDialogState extends State<SimpleDialog> {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final TextEditingController _textEditingController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    baseurl = Prefs().geturlBase();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      title: Text('Base URL'),
      content: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: TextFormField(
            keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
            maxLines: null,
            //controller: _textEditingController,
            initialValue: baseurl,
            onChanged: (val) {
              setState(() {
                baseurl = val;
                print(baseurl);
              });
            },
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: "Please Enter Base Url",
              border:
                  OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
            ),
            validator: (value) {
              // return value!.isNotEmpty ? null : "Enter Base Url";
              return Uri.parse(value.toString()).host == ''
                  ? "Enter Base Url"
                  : null;
            },
          )),
      actions: <Widget>[
        Center(
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              buildShowDialog(context);
              if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                baseurl = baseurl.trim();
                checkBaseUrl(baseurl, context);
                // Navigator.of(context).pop();
                print('baseurl=====base------$baseurl');
              }
            },
            child: Container(
              width: 100,
              height: 40,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.blue,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
              ),
              child: Text(
                "Connect",
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

This is a dialog box where I can change my baseURL. Now, I need history when I touch textfield, history should appear and I can able to select the data from history to text field and also able to delete history, not all history particular data from that list. how can I able to achieve this kinda logic??.

Comment: You can use https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_typeahead package to acheive the desired result

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59860840/how-to-use-searchdelegate-to-show-recent-search-history-in-flutter or use plugin https://pub.dev/packages/input_history_text_field

Answer (score 1):

An [input_history_text_field](https://pub.dev/packages/input_history_text_field) widget is automatically saved and suggested as you type.